# How to generate sinc wave using verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx

I'm making an "Arbitrary waveform generator" on FPGA. currently, I'm working on generating "sinc" wave using FPGA [using verilog].

For a fixed frequency, I can make the sinc using LUT on a ROM, but I need to give the option to make sinc of user-defined frequency.

So, any good idea how to make it???

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sinc or sine? You say `sinc` in one sentence and `sin` in another.

Comment: sinc... sorry for the spelling mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use a LUT for the variable frequency `sin(x)` function.

Just generate a LUT of 1000 or so (depending on your desired resolution) entries of a single cycle of a sine wave. Then you decide how many entries to jump through each clock cycle based on the desired frequency.

As an example, if your clock is 1MHz, and the desired output frequency is 1KHz, then you step to the next LUT entry every clock (complete the period in 1000 clock cycles). If the desired output frequency is 10KHz, then you jump 10 entries in the LUT every cycle. (complete the period in 100 clock cycles)

To get the sinc though `sin(x)/x`, I think you will need to implement a division circuit, as I can't think of any way around that.

Comment: Yeah, I used LUT for variable sine wave, i.e., DDS.

Comment: So is your real question then just trying to find a way to avoid the division circuit?

Comment: And I was thinking to make a sinc using the same technique like sine... i.e., make a LUT using ROM and pick different number of points/cycle according to frequency. 

So what do you think, is that possible..??

Comment: I didn't think so before, but now I think it might be possible to just use a LUT in the same fashion. Just program a sinc(x) function to a LUT and jump through the steps based on the input frequency.

Comment: Actually my question is to make as easy as possible. Using divider requires more resources and may reduce my design's max speed. So I think that it would be better to avoid divider circuit.

What do you say? Should I use divider circuit?

Comment: I think you can probably do it with LUT alone.